# Creating UI using PHP CLI on Windows

Tags: php, user-interface, command-line-interface

I am writing a small command-line script in PHP for automated text-processing and database stuff and want some UI for it when I run it on Windows.

The problem is, I can't find anything good which do that. The best I can do seems like `echo`ing backspace characters and overwriting stuff.

So, are there any way I can do some UI on Windows better than `echo`ing backspaces and carriage returns? (Extensions, frameworks, snippets, anything)

Comment: I'm not sure about a *nice* UI but you can create a command-line UI using `ncurses`.  More info here http://php.net/manual/en/book.ncurses.php and a basic tutorial here http://devzone.zend.com/173/using-ncurses-in-php/

Comment: If you need to return the cursor to position 0 in a line, use `echo "\r";`

Comment: @Ding I believe ncurses does not work with Windows